# Which media player to sync with my LG Nexus 5?

Tags: sync, banshee, 14.04, mtp, nexus-4

I have an LG Nexus 5 phone running Andriod 4.4.2 and a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

When attached via USB2 or USB3 I can mount the file system on the phone without issue and can manually transfer files but this is not the rich functionality that I'm after.

I have tried using Banshee 2.6.2 to sync music and playlists but as soon as I attach my phone Banshee hangs and tells me: "Oops! Something went wrong. Unhandled error message: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Mount' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/mount/1 "

I do like the Banshee interface and functionality but I can't see how I can carry on using it if I'm unable to use it to manage my music on my phone.

Any advice on solving the issue or recommend an alternative software package that will offer the same functions would be appreciated?

Comment: I've now upgraded to Andriod 4.4.3 in the vain hope that something may have been fixed.... Alas no! Still have the same errors.

Comment: still no luck in 4.4.4 :(

Comment: Nope 4.4.4 still fails

Comment: I had high hopes that with the release of Andriod L (5.0) Lollipop my issues may be resolved but again I'm disappointed.

Comment: Just have a little bit more patience until http://www.ubuntu.com/phone hits the market...

At least you've got an Android already!  I've got a dinosaur 1.1!  ;)

Comment: Now working on 15.04 and Android 5.1 and still looking for a solution to syncing. I still have to keep my Windows dual boot just to keep my playlists and sync to work. Has anybody got any recommendations for an alternative to Banshee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use banshee?
I strongly recommend **Clementine**

```
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

after a while of use, this one really gives me all features a media player can give me. I use an "intelligent playlist" to generate the next playlist out of my favorites (rating, stars, last played, skipped, etc) for my phone.
Wanna give it a try?

Comment: Thanks zulu34sx. THis is exactly what I've done. I installed Clementine a few months ago and have got used to it. I'm always open to good suggestions and willing to change the way I operate. I've found Clementine to be an excellent media player which meets pretty much all my requirements.

Comment: P.S. I'm now using Andriod 6 on a Nexus 5x and Ubuntu 15.10 and all is sweet.